# How to easily convert Debian script to RPM script?

Tags: debian, centos, scripting, rpm

I'm aiming to ***translate*** a Debian package to an RPM package to install it on a CentOS Linux 7 (Red Hat).
I used `alien` to accomplish it: `alien --to-rpm --scripts --keep-version debian_pkg.deb`. However, when I want to install the created rpm package, an error is raised from the `preinst` script. I saw online that there is a high likelihood that scripts written for Debian packages won’t work for RPM packages.

Is there an easy way to translate a Debian script to an RPM script? If not, is there any common patterns when you want to do the conversion?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need help resolving the immediate issue, maybe post a separate question with the actual generated `preinst` script and a description of how it's not working.

Comment: No the scripts in a .deb generally do not translate you are better off either finding a .rpm, extracting the contents of the .deb and manually installing, or building from source code.

Answer (score 1):

No, the best effort there is is `alien` and the problems it has are not easily rectified programmatically.

If you do find that you know how to fix something it doesn't do properly, I'm sure the maintainers would welcome a patch.